# Phonegap app unexpectedly restarts

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I have a strange problem with a Phonegap Android app.
I have a button with `ontouchend='dosomeajax()'`.

If I execute the function through the remote inspector console everything goes well, but if I tap on the button, the function unexpectedly returns ajax error and it restarts(reloads the main html page).

```
D/com.appgyver.preview.ESWebViewClient( 3632): shouldInterceptRequest: http://myserver.com/action.php
D/com.appgyver.preview.ESWebViewClient( 3632): onLoadResource: http://debug.phonegap.com/ws/target/112xxxxx4
D/com.appgyver.preview.ESWebViewClient( 3632): onLoadResource: http://myserver.com/action.php
D/com.appgyver.preview.ESWebViewClient( 3632): shouldOverrideUrlLoading: http://localhost/index.html, http://localhost/index.html?
D/com.appgyver.preview.ESWebViewClient( 3632): Overriding url loading for http://localhost/index.html?
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Give us some more insights. What does the function do?! Maybe you have a form submission button that the default event is that it reloads the page after is sends the data. If that is the case please use e.PreventDefault from jQuery to prevent the default behaviour of the DOM element. Keep us updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show how you declare the button, if it is something like this:

```
<a href="#" ontouchend="dosomeajax()">click me</a>
```

it could be that the `href` triggers the page reload. Just remove the href or make it `href="javascript:false;"` or so.